# Change ref of hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I ran into this and couldn't find the answer. I am trying to see if it is possible to "change" the reference of a hash. In other words, I have a hash, and a function that returns a hashref, and I want to make my hash point to the location in memory specified by this ref, instead of copying the contents of the hash it points to. The code looks something like this:

```
%hash = $h->hashref;
```

My obvious guess was that it should look like this:

```
\%hash = $h->hashref;
```

but that gives the error:

> Can't modify reference constructor in scalar assignment

I tried a few other things, but nothing worked. Is what I am attempting actually possible?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how references in PHP behave, so I am not sure.

Comment: `$h->hashref` is a function in an object that returns a hash ref. Specifically, it is the dbi function `$sth->fetchrow_hashref`, but I didn't want to confuse people into thinking the question is about dbi.

Comment: That would dereference the hashref (and copy the values to %hash), so it's the opposite of what I want.

Comment: It isn't exactly clear what you are trying to do, I must confess.

Comment: Normally, `\%hash` returns a reference to a hash, you can then treat that as a scalar (and assign to something like $hashref) and then dereference that and get the hash pointed to in memory, so modifying %$hashref modifies the elements in %hash. What I want to do is to go in the other direction, and overwrite %hash with the $hashref memory location, so in essence it is the "same" hash as the one referenced by $hashref.

Comment: Yes, it didn't answer my question.

Comment: You _are_ looking for a perl answer, right? just asking, because your first comment is about PHP.

Comment: "i alarmed alien" deleted his comment asking about whether it's like PHP.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. I was asking if the OP was trying to emulate the way references function in PHP. I deleted the comment since it wasn't relevant. The code and tags for the question are all Perl-y.

Comment: I think you should explain what it is that you're trying to do. I am sure there's a better way. If you are unclear about how to use the returned reference then please say so and you will get assistance.

Answer (score 2):

An experimental feature which would seemingly allow you to do exactly what you're describing [has been added](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ABIGAIL/perl-5.21.5/pod/perldelta.pod) to Perl 5.21.5, which is a development release (see "Aliasing via reference").

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want:

```
use Data::Alias;
alias %hash = $h->hashref;
```

Or if %hash is a package variable, you can instead just do:

```
*hash = $h->hashref;
```

But either way, this should almost always be avoided; simply use the hash reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To answer your question, I was just writing some code which was already using a hash, so I was trying to do this simply because I thought it was possible (and not problematic). I might resort to just using refs as my solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but…

References in Perl are *scalars*. You are trying to alias the return value. This actually is possible, but you should *not* do this, since it involves messing with the symbol table. Furthermore, this only works for globals (declared with `our`): If you assign a hashref to the glob `*hash` it will assign to the symbol table entry `%hash`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

sub a_hashref{{a => "one", b => "two"}}

our %hash;
*hash = a_hashref;

printf "%3s -> %s\n", $_, $hash{$_} foreach keys %hash;
```

**This is bad style!** It isn't in PBP (directly, but consider section 5.1: “non-lexicals should be avoided”) and won't be reported by `perlcritic`, but you shouldn't pollute the package namespace for a little syntactic fanciness. Furthermore it doesn't work with lexical variables (which is what you might want to use most of the time, because they are lexically scoped, not package wide).

Another problem is, that if the `$h->hashref` method changes its return type, you'll suddenly assign to another table entry! (So if `$h->hashref` changes its return type to an arrayref, you assign to @hash, good luck detecting that). You could circumvent that by checking if `$h->hashref` really returns a hashref with `'HASH' eq ref` $h->hashref`, but that would defeat the purpose.

What is the problem with just keeping the reference? If you get a reference, just store it in a scalar:

```
$hash = $h->hashref
```

To read more about the global symbol table, take a look at [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables) and consider [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) for the `*FOO{THING}` syntax, which sadly isn't for lvalues.

To achieve what you want, you could check out the several aliasing [modules on cpan](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Alias). [Data::Alias](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Alias) or [Lexical::Alias](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lexical::Alias) seem to fit your purpose. Also if you are interested in `tie` semantics and/or don't want to use `XS` modules, [Tie::Alias](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Alias) might be worth a shoot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To answer your question, I was just writing some code and was trying to do this, simply because I thought it was possible (and not non-trivial or problematic). I might resort to just using refs as my solution. Thanks again

Comment: @Insaner: Okay, but if you want to live up to your username you should use them as many times as possible. If someone else might want to use their code, then probably don't. I added a modules section, you could consider one of them since it only adds 2 lines of code (and some installation, but with `cpanm` that's just one command today)

Answer (score 1):

This question is really old, but Perl now allows this sort of thing as an experimental feature:

```
use v5.22;

use experimental qw(refaliasing);

my $first = {
    foo => 'bar',
    baz => 'quux',
    };

\my %hash = $first;
```

- [Create named variable aliases with ref aliasing](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/08/create-named-variable-aliases-with-ref-aliasing/)
- [Mix assignment and reference aliasing with declared_refs](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2018/09/mix-assignment-and-reference-aliasing-with-declared_refs/)